# How to divide a number by 32 in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, architecture, arm, division

Is there any way possible to do a division operation on ARM

```
int sum =0;
for (int i=0; i<32 ; i++)
{
 sum+= i*2;
 i++;
}
int avg = sum/32;
```

Here is my code:

```
Area Prob2, CODE
Entry
mov R0,#0 //R0 = sum
mov R1,#0 //R1 = i
Loop CMP R1,#32
BGE EXT // exit loop
mul R2, R1,#2 // multiply
ADD R0,R0,R2 // the addtion
ADD R1,R1,#1
ADD R1,R1,#1
B loop
EXT
END
```

I can't find a way to do the division and is it even correct for the first part

Comment: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syl-ARM/7-ARM/arithm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Integer) division by 32 is easily achieved with a **right bit shift**, because 32 is 2⁵.

In Java you would write:

```
int avg = sum >> 5;
```

I'm not familiar with the assembly syntax you're using but [going by this example](http://www-mdp.eng.cam.ac.uk/web/library/enginfo/mdp_micro/lecture4/lecture4-3-2.html) I would guess this will compute R0 (sum) divided by 32 and store the result in R1:

```
MOV R1, R0, LSR #5
```

Comment: Yup, 32-bit ARM doesn't have dedicated shift instructions because almost any instruction can have a shifted input operand.  `lsr r1, r0, #5` is a pseudo-instruction for that `mov`.  Note that `LSR` is a *logical* right shift; in Java you'd use `>>>` to get it.  And `ASR` (`>>`) is only equivalent to `/2` for positive integers; otherwise they round differently.  But apparently we can assume signed positive, or unsigned here.

Answer (score 1):

Your Java code is a perfect valid C code, it means that you can compile your C code and get the asm (and most probably it's going to be the optimal translation).

`MOV` is a perfect valid solution, but I think it is important to say that the compiler(*) will translate the shift to [`ASR`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0204/j/arm-and-thumb-instructions/general-data-processing-instructions/asr--lsl--lsr--ror--and-rrx) instead of `MOV`. From ARM documentation:

> These instructions are synonyms for MOV instructions with shifted register second operands.

> Arithmetic Shift Right. This instruction is a preferred synonym for MOV instructions with shifted register operands.

[i.e.](https://godbolt.org/z/bPMrfs), the code:

```
int funct(int sum) {
    int avg;
    avg = sum>>5;
    return avg;
}
```

will turn into:

```
   asr     r0, r0, #5
   bx      lr
```

[According to ARM](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0597/h/base-instructions-alphabetic-order/asr-immediate-arithmetic-shift-right-immediate-an-alias-of-mov-movs-register), the only difference between `MOV` and `ASR` is:

> This is an alias of MOV, MOVS (register). This means:
>
> - The encodings in this description are named to match the encodings of
>   MOV, MOVS (register).
> - The description of MOV, MOVS (register) gives
>   the operational pseudocode for this instruction.

Note (*):

> The ASR ARM instruction is available in all architectures.
>
> The ASR 32-bit Thumb instruction is available in ARMv6T2 and above.
>
> The ASR 16-bit Thumb instruction is available in ARMv4T and above.

Comment: *the compiler(*) will translate the shift to ASR instead of MOV* - Those are different mnemonics for literally the same machine instruction (opcode).  Explaining that they're the same thing is maybe important, but it's *not* important which synonym GCC and clang pick.